# Menu Still Show When Change @media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have 2 sidebar (side-bar and side-bar-mobile). First sidebar i want to see it when screen in width > 768px, so i do that.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
       .side-bar{
            display: block;
       }
       .side-bar-mobile{
            display: none;
       }
}
```

And when screen in width < 768px, side-bar is hide and side-bar-mobile is show toggle when i click a button.

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
       .side-bar{
            display: none;
       }
       .side-bar-mobile{
            display: none;
       }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#toggle-menu').on('click', function(e){
        $('.side-bar-mobile').slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
})
```

Side-bar-mobile is slide good. But when i resize my window to normal size (width > 768px), the side-bar-mobile is still show. What can i do now? I think problem in slidetoggle functions, it make side-bar-mobile is show when i resize window. But i can't solve this problem. Help me! Thank you.

Comment: according to your question side-bar-mobile must be shown on media screen < 768 `.side-bar-mobile{
            display: block;
       }`

Comment: This is likely because slideToggle is adding `style="display: block;"` to `.side-bar-mobile` when it is shown. This inline style is over riding the rules you have setup in your CSS file. One way round this would be to remove the inline style and add a class which sets `.side-bar-mobile` to `display: block;` in slideToggle's complete function.

Comment: Thanks Hidden Hobbes. So according to your comment. I should use removeAttr("style") in jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, that should do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When screen width > 768 the side-bar-mobile must be hidden no matter what.

So in order to do that you need to register window resize listener like this:

```
window.onresize = function(){
   var h = window.innerHeight 
           || document.documentElement.clientHeight 
           || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
    var w = window.innerWidth 
            || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
            || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;

    if(w > 768 ){
        $('.side-bar-mobile').css({display:"none"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also put window resize condition.
try this one

```
$(function(){
var nb = $('#toggle-menu');
var n = $('.side-bar');

$(window).on('resize', function(){
if(nb.is(':hidden') && n.is(':hidden') && $(window).width() >768) {
$('.side-bar').show().addClass('keep-nav-closed');
}
});
```